# iOS: @synchronized block no working

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uistoryboardsegue

I'm trying to avoid this crash:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Receiver (<myNewViewController: 0x7ff3c5209330>) has no segue with identifier 'myNewViewController''
```

Using @synchronized. Here is my implementation:

ViewController.m:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.canLoadViewController = YES;
}

-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    NSLog(self.canLoadViewController ? @"Yes" : @"No");
    @synchronized(self) {
        if (self.canLoadViewController == YES) {
            [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"myNewViewController" sender:self];
        }
    }
}

-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"myNewViewController"]){
       self.canLoadViewController = NO;
        myNewViewController *vc = (myNewViewController*)[segue destinationViewController];
        vc.title = @"azul";
    }
}
```

The problem is viewDidAppear is been call twice and the value of self.canLoadViewController is not the same as the one set in prepareForSegue.

Any of you knows why @synchronized is not working ? or what I'm doing wrong?

I'll really appreciate your help.

Comment: It is nothing to do with @synchronized. There is no segue with the specified identifier in your storyboard from the current scene

Comment: @Paulw11, the problem is viewDidAppear is been call twice and the value of self.canLoadViewController it's not been consistent after been set in prepareForSegue

Comment: Have you perhaps set the same view controller class in two different scenes

Comment: @Paulw11 How can I check if the same instance of view controller? or how can manage to make everything in the same instance of the view controller

Comment: The problem is almost certainly in your storyboard. Check your view controller classes

Comment: The only reason to ever use `@synchronized` is to ensure the block of code can't be run concurrently from two different threads. `viewDidAppear:` is only ever called from the main thread. It can't be called from two different threads concurrently unless you have bad code that attempts to present the view controller from a background thread. The fix is not the use of `@synchronized`. The fix is to ensure you only perform UI code on the main thread.